# How can i load tokenizer on my debian server from hugging face?

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers

Recently I am dealing with the vector DB Milvus and I've found the [resource](https://github.com/towhee-io/examples/blob/main/nlp/text_search/search_article_in_medium.ipynb) to learn how to write code for my purpose on my Debian server.Every time I try to run code related to hugging face(`model_name="facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base"`), it give me error `OSError: Can't load tokenizer for "$(model)"`.So I then try the code searched from [hugging face](https://huggingface.co/facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base#how-to-get-started-with-the-model) below both on my server and Mac, and without surprise it fails on my server. However, when I run the code on my mac, things goes right:

```py
from transformers import DPRContextEncoder, DPRContextEncoderTokenizer
tokenizer = DPRContextEncoderTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base")
model = DPRContextEncoder.from_pretrained("facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base")
input_ids = tokenizer("Hello, is my dog cute ?", return_tensors="pt")["input_ids"]
embeddings = model(input_ids).pooler_output
```

and the output log for mac is below:

```bash
tokenizer_config.json: 100%|████████████████| 28.0/28.0 [00:00<00:00, 42.5kB/s]
vocab.txt: 100%|█████████████████████████████| 232k/232k [00:00<00:00, 512kB/s]
tokenizer.json: 100%|███████████████████████| 466k/466k [00:00<00:00, 1.44MB/s]
config.json: 100%|████████████████████████████| 492/492 [00:00<00:00, 1.49MB/s]
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is not the same type as the class this function is called from. It may result in unexpected tokenization.
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is 'DPRQuestionEncoderTokenizer'.
The class this function is called from is 'DPRContextEncoderTokenizer'.
pytorch_model.bin: 100%|████████████████████| 438M/438M [00:33<00:00, 13.2MB/s]
Some weights of the model checkpoint at facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base were not used when initializing DPRContextEncoder: ['ctx_encoder.bert_model.pooler.dense.bias', 'ctx_encoder.bert_model.pooler.dense.weight']
- This IS expected if you are initializing DPRContextEncoder from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing DPRContextEncoder from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
```

And I've searched the Web and noticed there maybe something wrong with my proxy, but I don't know how to set the proxy of my server.And I also wonder should I download every model I need to solve this problem?

Tried:

1. [OSError: Can't load tokenizer #26612](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/26612)
2. [What to do when HuggingFace throws “Can’t load tokenizer”](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/what-to-do-when-huggingface-throws-cant-load-tokenizer/23046)

   - I don't know how to do the thing in the [reply](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/what-to-do-when-huggingface-throws-cant-load-tokenizer/23046/7) inside the post.

**Edit: The full error stacktrace is below:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/a.py", line 2, in <module>
    tokenizer = DPRContextEncoderTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base")
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/milvus/hello/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 2012, in from_pretrained
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant files for a DPRContextEncoderTokenizer tokenizer.
```

Comment: Please add the whole error stacktrace.

Comment: @cronoik, I've added the error detail.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? You can provide the proxy information as a parameter for `from_pretrained` (compare [doc](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained.proxies)).

Comment: Yes, i'm using the VPN both on my server and my mac, if the error is related to the VPN, why the mac works well?